# regex to not match part of string

Tags: regex

I am searching for time in multiple formats like:

```
1:00 pm
1 pm
10:38 am
8am
9p.m.
etc...
```

I came up with below regex:

```
([0-9][0-9]?)(\\:([0-9][0-9])(\\:([0-9][0-9]))?)? ?([ap]\\.?m\\.?)
```

For example, if there is a time like `10:5` am then it matches partially as `5 am`

I do not want to match `10:5 am` at all if entire time is not matched with above regex pattern.

Is there any way not to match `5 am` partially in `10:5 am`?

Comment: Will a valid hour always be preceded by a space and/or at the beginning of a line?

Comment: Yes. The time can be part of a paragraph with space before or beginning of a line

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I am using regex in c# to process the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing with the `=match` operator in **PowerShell**, this seems to do the trick:
`'(?<=^|\s)(?:\d{1,2}(?:\:\d{2}){0,2})\s?[ap]\.?m\.?'`

```
$times = '1:00 pm,1 pm,10:38 am,8am,9p.m.,10:5 am,7:59 pm'.split(',')

$times | ForEach{
If ($_ -match '(?<=^|\s)(?:\d{1,2}(?:\:\d{2}){0,2})\s?[ap]\.?m\.?') {
$matches
} Else {echo ($_ + ' does not match')}
}
```

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              1:00 pm
0                              1 pm
0                              10:38 am
0                              8am
0                              9p.m.
10:5 am does not match
0                              7:59 pm
```

`(?<=^|\s)` <- Positive LookBehind (must be beginning of line or preceded by space)

`(?:\d{1,2}(?:\:\d{2}){0,2})` <- One or two digit hour + optional minutes & seconds. (nested non-capturing groups)

`\s?` <- Optional space.

`[ap]\.?m\.?` <- am|pm|a.m.|p.m. Can be grouped & made optional (for 24-hour time): `(?:[ap]\.?m\.?)?`

Comment: Awesome :) works fine. Thanks